# distutils.dir_util.copy_tree expects a file in destination before copying

Tags: python, distutils

I want to copy the contents of one directory to another, using `copy_tree` function for doing this. Below is my code:

```
copy_tree('/opt/Deployment/scripts/image', '/opt/Deployment/dist-packages/job-123')
```

A couple of files from the directory `image` are getting copied into `job-123`, but after that, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 305, in _dispatch_request
    res = self._HANDLERS[handler](self, *args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 535, in _handle_call
    return self._local_objects[oid](*args, **dict(kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpyc/core/service.py", line 157, in exposed_execute
    execute(text, self.exposed_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 2, in execute
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "../installModel.py", line 17, in <module>
    copy_tree('/opt/Deployment/scripts/image', '/opt/Deployment/dist-packages/job-123')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dir_util.py", line 163, in copy_tree
    verbose=verbose, dry_run=dry_run))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dir_util.py", line 167, in copy_tree
    dry_run=dry_run)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/file_util.py", line 148, in copy_file
    _copy_file_contents(src, dst)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/file_util.py", line 44, in _copy_file_contents
    fdst = open(dst, wb)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /opt/Deployment/dist-packages/job-123/lib/utils.pyc
```

Now this file `utils.pyc` is in the source directory in the `lib` subdirectory, it should get copied to the same subdirectory in the destination. Why is `copy_tree` expecting it to be there already and throwing an error?

Comment: Why not [shutil.copytree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree)?

Comment: `shutil.copytree` doesn't overwrite files if the directory exist. I can remove the existing tree manually but isn't `copy_tree` supposed to do that automatically?